# Why is my recyclerview emptying when I restart my app?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview inside a tab of a tabbed layout, so in a fragment. Adding and removing items from the recyclerview works perfectly fine but when i refresh the app (open the recent apps on my phone and close it) the recyclerview is empty i.e when the app restarts. Please let me know if there is any code you need to see.

Here is the code for my fragment:

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.AlarmClock;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import static rongorai.wakeup.MainActivity.alarms;

public class Tab1 extends Fragment
{
    /**Fragment stuff-------------------------------------------*/
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;
    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    /**Actual stuff--------------------------------------------*/
    private FloatingActionButton fab;
    private Button inserttest;
    private Button removetest;

    private RecyclerView rv;
    public static MainAdapter rva;

    public static TextView txtNoAlarms;

    /**Methods-------------------------------------------------*/
    public Tab1()
    {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static Tab1 newInstance(String param1, String param2)
    {
        Tab1 fragment = new Tab1();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null)
        {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab1, container, false);
        fab = view.findViewById(R.id.fab);
        rv = view.findViewById(R.id.rv);
        inserttest = view.findViewById(R.id.inserttest);
        removetest = view.findViewById(R.id.removettest);
        txtNoAlarms = view.findViewById(R.id.txtNoAlarm);

        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), NewAlarm.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        removetest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                /*if (alarms.size() > 0) {
                    alarms.remove(0);
                }
                rva.notifyItemRemoved(0);
                if (alarms.size() == 0 & txtNoAlarms.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE) {
                    txtNoAlarms.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }*/

                Intent intent = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM);
                intent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, 21);
                intent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, 6);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

        inserttest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                alarms.add(new Alarm("alarm name", true, true, true, true, new boolean[] {true, false}, 15, 27));
                rva.notifyItemInserted(0);
                if (alarms.size() != 0 & txtNoAlarms.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                    txtNoAlarms.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
                updateAlarmVals();
            }
        });

        //Recycler View-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
        rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
        rva = new MainAdapter(alarms, getActivity());
        rv.setAdapter(rva);
        rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        /*rva.setOnItemClickListener(new MainAdapter.OnItemClickedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(int position) {
                //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "clicked " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), EditAlarm.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });*/

        return view;
    }

    public static void updateAlarmVals() {
        Tab2.alarmvals.setText("" + alarms.size() + "\n");
        for (Alarm i: alarms) {
            Tab2.alarmvals.setText(Tab2.alarmvals.getText().toString() +
                    i.toString() + "\n");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context)
    {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener)
        {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else
        {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach()
    {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener
    {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

Comment: are you using a database or any mean of saving the data? If not you're not saving any progress, thus the recycler view is empty on the start of your app.

Comment: Please post all the related code first

Comment: please provide complete code

Comment: I am not using any database

Comment: I uploaded the code for my fragment. If anything else is needed please let me know what; this is my first time asking a question on stack.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to handle `onResume()` in your fragment and update the recyclerview.

```
 @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
```

Comment: I tried adding this code, but it didn't make any difference.